File upload in react native expo project not working
I get No file uploaded as the response from the backend.
import ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
export const UpdateProfile = () => {
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const [formPostImg, setFormPostImg] = useState("");

  const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState<Record<string, string>>({
    profile: "",
  });

  const openImageLibraryKeyMessage = async () => {
    const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== "granted") {
      alert("Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!");
    }

    if (status === "granted") {
      const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsEditing: true,
      });

      if (!result.canceled) {
        setFormPostImg(result.assets[0].uri);
        console.log({ formPostImg });
      }
    }
  };

  const handleUpdateProfile = async () => {
    console.log("clicked");
    console.log({ formPostImg });

    const formBody = new FormData();
    formBody.append("address", address);
    formBody.append("img", formPostImg);
    try {
      const res = await updateProfileFn({
        formBody,
        setErrMsg,
      });
      if (res && res.message.includes("success")) {
        console.log("success");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // disable empty object error
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.mainBox}>
      {errMsg.profile && <Text>{errMsg.profile}</Text>}
      <View>
        <Text>Address</Text>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={setAddress}
          value={address}
          placeholder="Enter address"
          style={styles.textInput}
        />
      </View>

      <Pressable onPress={openImageLibraryKeyMessage}>
        <Text>Pick image</Text>
      </Pressable>

      <Pressable onPress={handleUpdateProfile}>
        <Text>Update</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

I console.log({ formPostImg }); and get a response similar to
LOG  {"formPostImg": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Ffrontend-a5b88748-c8d6-412d-b8cc-ee88decfab14/ImagePicker/72bb7e65-9d16-4a78-a14e-009cd8cca53c.jpeg"}

which shows the image is being stored in state however when I try to upload, I get the error "No file uploaded" from the backend
This is the function I'm calling
async function updateProfileFn({
  formBody,
  setErrMsg,
}: {
  formBody: FormData;
  setErrMsg: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Record<string, string>>>;
}): Promise<ResSuccess | undefined> {
  const url = `${BASE_URL}/api/v1/users/updateProfile`;

  const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("token");
  console.log({ formBody });

  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: "PATCH",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: formBody,
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    const exactErrorMsg = await res.json();
    const errorMsgString = JSON.stringify(exactErrorMsg);
    const errorMsg = JSON.parse(errorMsgString).error;

    // Set the error message in the state
    setErrMsg((prev) => ({ ...prev, profile: errorMsg }));

    // Throw an error to stop further execution
    return;
  }

  const data: ResSuccess = await res.json();

  console.log({ data });

  return data;
}
export default updateProfileFn;

This is the backend code for more context
export const updateProfile: express.RequestHandler = (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
) => {
  const { id: user_id } = getUserIDAndToken(req);

  if (!user_id) {
    res.status(401).json({ error: "Unauthorized" });
    return;
  }

  upload.single("img")(req, res, async (err) => {
    if (err) {
      if (err.message === "Unexpected field") {
        // console.log(error.message);

        res.status(400).json({ error: "Maximum of 1 image allowed" });
        return;
      }
    }

    const {
      address,
      phone_number,
      account_name,
      email,
      tag,
    }: {
      address: string;
      phone_number: string;
      account_name: string;
      email: string;
      tag: string;
    } = req.body;
    console.log({ address, phone_number, account_name, email, tag });

    // create uniqueIdentifier for the image
    const uniqueIdentifier = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);

    // create publicId for the image for cloudinary
    const publicId = `profile-img-${uniqueIdentifier}`;

    console.log(req.files);
    console.log(req.file?.path);

    if (!req.file) {
      res.status(400).json({ error: "No file uploaded" });
      return;
    }

    if (!address || !phone_number || !account_name || !email) {
      res.status(400).json({ error: "Missing required fields" });
      return;
    }

    try {
      const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, {
        public_id: publicId,
      });
      const imgURL = result.secure_url;
      console.log("imgURL", imgURL);

      pool.execute<ResultSetHeader>(
        `
                UPDATE users
                SET img = ?, address = ?, phone_number = ?, account_name = ?, email = ?, tag = ?
                WHERE id = ?
                `,
        [imgURL, address, phone_number, account_name, email, tag, user_id],
        (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
            return;
          } else {
            console.log({ result });
            res.status(200).json({ message: "Profile updated successfully" });
          }
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
    }
  });
};

The log of these
console.log(req.files);
console.log(req.file?.path);

are both undefined

What are you using for your api to define your route?

This is my route
import { Router } from "express";
const router = Router();
import { updateProfile } from "../controllers/users/profile/update";
router.route("/updateProfile").patch(updateProfile);
export default router;
And this is my index.ts
import userRouter from "./routes/users";
app.use("/api/v1/users", userRouter);

I think your issue might be your formData. I do this to upload an image using form data in react native:
      formData.append(
        `${image.name}`,      <=== Name of upload
        {
          uri: image.uri,
          name: image.name,
          type: 'image/jpeg',
        } as any,                    <== Blob
        `${image.name}`       <=== FileName
      );

This is what worked for me so hopefully this is your issue as well!

Here the error I got with your method.
o overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 3, '(name: string, value: string | Blob): void', gave the following error.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'uri' does not exist in type 'Blob'.
Overload 2 of 3, '(name: string, value: string): void', gave the following error.
Argument of type '{ type: string; uri: string; name: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Overload 3 of 3, '(name: string, blobValue: Blob, filename?: string | undefined): void', gave the following error...

On this line.
formBody.append("img", {type: "image/jpeg", uri: formPostImg, name: 'file.jpg'});

So did this work for you? Or are you still having issues?

Reading your comment above if you are using typescript I was having issues with types as well I basically just cast the blob as any because I couldn't get the types fixed maybe someone smarter then me can explain the type miss match. I will edit my answer to cast to any.

It works, the typescript error exists. Other than that, the upload works as expected. Thanks.

To remove the typescript error and if eslint will give a warning when you cast as any you can cast as unknown as blob. Like this.
formBody.append("img", {
type: "image/jpeg",
uri: formPostImg,
name: "file.jpg",
} as unknown as Blob);
